# When to use PRIVATE vs INTERFACE compile options/definitions on a target in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a C++ CMake project with 3 targets:

1. An Interface Library target `MyProjectInterfaces` (defines some interfaces in hpp files)
2. Library `MyProjectFoo` (implements 1/2 of the interfaces in MyProjectInterfaces)
3. Library `MyProjectBar` (implements the other 1/2 of interfaces in MyProjectInterfaces)

Downstreams projects that consume my library may want to implement the `MyProjectInterfaces` interfaces themselves, or use the `Foo` implementations, or the `Bar` implementations, or both.

I want to add some compile features/options/definitions to all of the targets in my project while minimizing code duplication. I know of two ways to do this.

METHOD 1: The easiest way is to add them to `MyProjectInterfaces` with `INTERFACE` scope:

```
    set(DEBUG_COMPILE_OPTIONS
        -Wall -Werror
    )
    set(RELEASE_COMPILE_OPTIONS
    
    )
            
    target_compile_features(MyProjectInterfaces INTERFACE
        cxx_std_17
    )
    
    target_compile_definitions(MyProjectInterfaces INTERFACE
        SDK_VERSION_MAJOR=${CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}
        SDK_VERSION_MINOR=${CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
        SDK_VERSION_PATCH=${CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH}
        )
    
    target_compile_options(MyProjectInterfaces INTERFACE
        $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${DEBUG_COMPILE_OPTIONS}>
        $<$<CONFIG:Release>:${RELEASE_COMPILE_OPTIONS}>
    )
```

METHOD 2: Alternatively I can change the scope to `PRIVATE`, wrap the `target_compile_XXX` calls in a macro/function, and call it for each target.

```
    macro(set_options myTarget)
    target_compile_features(${myTarget} PRIVATE
        cxx_std_17
    )
    
    target_compile_definitions(${myTarget} PRIVATE
        SDK_VERSION_MAJOR=${CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}
        SDK_VERSION_MINOR=${CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
        SDK_VERSION_PATCH=${CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH}
        )
    
    target_compile_options(${myTarget} PRIVATE
        $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${DEBUG_COMPILE_OPTIONS}>
        $<$<CONFIG:Release>:${RELEASE_COMPILE_OPTIONS}>
    )
    endmacro()
    
    # This probably won't work or be necessary because its an interface library target?
    # set_options(MyProjectInterface) 
    
    # Set compile options on actual compiled libraries
    set_options(MyProjectFoo)
    set_options(MyProjectBar)
```

As far as I'm aware both methods propagate all the definitions/options I want to each target in my project. However, METHOD 1 will also propagate these options/definitions to consuming projects. **Is that desirable?**

There's lots of documentation on the internet on how to pass the `PRIVATE`/`PUBLIC`/`INTERFACE` arguments into `target_compile_XXX(...)`, but I have been able to find very little on how/when to choose between them.

Comment: Consider if you knew nothing about the library you were using.  Would you want it to automatically set those options when you link against it?  I.e. if the library headers only compile with C++17 then I would want that automatically applied, but I generally wouldn't want my debug builds to use `-Wall -Werror` just because I linked against some library.  The `SDK_VERSION_*` macros are less clear-cut, it really depends what they're used for.

Comment: @MilesBudnek That makes sense. Are there any examples of flags that you would 'obviously' want to propagate into your library? `SDK_VERSION_*` in my case probably should be propagated, but I think I will rename it to `MYPROJECT_SDK_VERSION_*` or similar to avoid clashing with consumer's defines.

Comment: I would generally want any flags or definitions that are required to compile and link against your library, and nothing else.  In short: if you would document it in your library's public how-to-use documentation then it makes sense to be `PUBLIC`/`INTERFACE`.  Anything else should be `PRIVATE` because consumers don't need it.  `PUBLIC` and `INTERFACE` exist so that consumers don't need to do anything extra to use your library.  Just `target_link_library` and everything automatically works.